# Linear PDE and shock waves

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Using the methods of characteristics for a linear partial differential equation, e.g.
$$u_t + au_x = f,$$

can there be a noncontinuous solution, i.e. is there any example where the characteristics do intersect? If not, why not?

Comment: You mean a PDE of the form $u_t+au_x = f$ ?

Comment: Yes! I corrected this in my posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the PDE $$ u_t +au_x = f$$
Note that, as $u=u(x,t) =u(x(t),t))$ it follows 
$$\frac{d}{dt} u = u_x \frac{dx}{dt} + u_t$$
comparing this with the PDE we get
\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dt} = a \\
& \frac{du}{dt} = f
\end{align}
This means the characteristic is described via $\frac{dx}{dt}=a$ which is equivalent $x = at+x_0$. Along this characteristic,$u$ changes with $\frac{du}{dt}=f$.

But as the characteristic is described via $x=at+x_0$ it is impossible to get intersecting charachteristics, as all have the same slope $a$.

[Here is also a nice video on Youtube which takes ~15min.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNP286WZw3o)